# Bind arraylist to jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, beans-binding

recently I wrote a C# application, that simply rendered the elements of a list ( named lst) of objects into a table, with the following code:

```
DataTable dt = Request.ListToDataTable(lst);
dw = new DataView(dt);
dw.Sort = "columnb ASC";
dataGridView1.DataSource = dw;
```

now i need to do something similar in java : is it possible? or i have to create a tablemodel and working with it? Let's say I've a list of Person objects, and I want to build a table containing surname, name and age. Is it possible to do it in a smart way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or i have to create a tablemodel

Yes you will need a custom TableModel.

You can use the [Bean Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/) which allows you to create the model and the table in two lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible. The question is: what web framework are you going to chose?
Most of them offer data binding on a proper model-view-controller concept.